# What is the "metaclass" way to do this?

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to write a program that accepts as input a number p and produces as output a type-constructor for a number that obeys integer arithmetic modulo p.

So far I have

```
def IntegersModP(p):
   N = type('IntegersMod%d' % p, (), {})

   def __init__(self, x): self.val = x % p
   def __add__(a, b): return N(a.val + b.val)
   ... (more functions) ...    

   attrs = {'__init__': __init__, '__add__': __add__, ... }

   for name, f in attrs.items():
      setattr(N, name, f)

   return N
```

This works fine, but I'd like to know what the Pythonic way to do this is, which I understand would use metaclasses.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to use a metaclass here, you can use a simple class statement and pass `p` to `__init__`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary this not acceptable, because you should not be able to add two instances with different moduli. (Which modulus would you use?)

Comment: @JeremyKun You can store the modulus in the instance itself and then later check two instances's modulus before actually performing operation on them.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This is a very inelegant solution.

Comment: @JeremyKun: Your answer doesn't check the moduluses at all. Adding two numbers with different moduluses gives nonsensical results.

Comment: @JeremyKun What makes you think metaclass would make it elegant?

Comment: @user2357112 This is a good point and now I see why I can't avoid some sort of check. I think this is where I'm starting to wish I had a stricter type system... A shot in the dark: is there an analogue of __add__ that only gets called if both operands are instances of the same type? That seems like it would not be very Pythonic.

Comment: Nope. No such method.

Comment: Metclasses can be useful for automatically creating all the needed dunder ( `__name__`) methods required by numeric operations, without having to type in all the method bodiers. Maybe the question is about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaclasses are for when your class needs to behave differently from a normal class or when you want to alter the behavior of the `class` statement. Neither of those apply here, so there's really no need to use a metaclass. In fact, you could just have one `ModularInteger` class with instances that record their value and modulus, but assuming you don't want to do that, it's still easy to do this with an ordinary class statement:

```
def integers_mod_p(p):
    class IntegerModP(object):
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.n = n % IntegerModP.p
        def typecheck(self, other):
            try:
                if self.p != other.p:
                    raise TypeError
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError
        def __add__(self, other):
            self.typecheck(other)
            return IntegerModP(self.n + other.n)
        def __sub__(self, other):
            ...
    IntegerModP.p = p
    IntegerModP.__name__ = 'IntegerMod{}'.format(p)
    return IntegerModP
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Indeed. I was going to have it handle that with a more sophisticated `typecheck`, but I got distracted and forgot.

Comment: I think my lack of complete satisfaction with this is that I want to avoid errors as much as possible (and eventually I plan to make this class more general, so I want to do some silent type conversions when possible). But I think you've shown me that I just need to think harder about how I want to organize things, and it's a good answer to my question as stated.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
def IntegerModP(p):  # class factory function
    class IntegerModP(object):
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.val = x % p
        def __add__(a, b):
            return IntegerModP(a.val + b.val)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.val)
        def __repr__(self):
            return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.val)

    IntegerModP.__name__ = 'IntegerMod%s' % p  # rename created class
    return IntegerModP

IntegerMod4 = IntegerModP(4)
i = IntegerMod4(3)
j = IntegerMod4(2)
print i + j        # 1
print repr(i + j)  # IntegerMod4(1)
```

Comment: You might want to store `p` on the class instead of as a closure variable for easier introspection, and add some type checking so doing math with numbers in different moduluses doesn't just give silently wrong results.

Comment: @user2357112: I'm only outlining a "Pythonic" way to construct such a class for the OP not implement something which has only vaguely been defined in the question -- besides, the final name of the class should be good enough for introspection purposes.